# Is it possible to edit the "Missing Index Details" template in SSMS?

Tags: ssms, showplan

When you turn on "Include Actual Execution Plan" and run a query in SSMS, the resultant plan can include information about missing index(es) that would make the query more performant. In that case, right-clicking the plan and selecting "Missing Index Details..." will script out that missing recommended index to a new window.

I'd like to modify the template for generating the missing index to conform to my organisation's SQL style guide, but I can't see any where or how to edit how that index is generated. I'm aware of [SSMS templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/template/templates-ssms) which can be tweaked, but can't find any reference to this particular template anywhere. Does anyone know if it's available for customisation, and if so where?